# WP7 - Ideal Project structure with scheduletaskproject

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, projects-and-solutions

For my WP7 app I currently have a the Main application Project - call it say"MainProj'  and another Project which is a  class library Project where I have defined my database (its a Sterling DB).  Lets call this project  'DBProject'.

Included in my 'MainProj' are my Views, ViewModels and a dataservice that  retrieves data from the database.  'MainProj' includes a reference to 'DBProj'

I an now including a PeriodicTask, so have added a third project - 'scheduletaskproject'.   My 'MainProj' references this and includes to fire off the Periodic task and its all working fine.

I am now about to extend my PeriodTask code, and, the code I want to access the database etc is all in my 'MainProj'.  I cannot add that as a reference as that will create a crircular reference.  Seems that I will have  to refactor alot of code out to make it accessible to both applications including the dataservice.  I was possibly even going  to utilise one of my viewmodels but suspect that may not be the right thing to do.

So just looking for advice as to what theright approach should be here as I clearly have to refactor some code.  As per a comment on a previous query, seems that there is a 5MB memory limit in the Periodic TAsk that may be awlward if I am accessing a database.   Are there any techiques in terms of refactoring the code that could help here?

- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move all code the ScheduledTask will reference to a separate assembly. Not only because of the memory limitations, but also because the ScheduledTask assembly cannot reference **any code whatsoever** that uses APIs that isn't supported in a Task (and there's quite a few of those).

Comment: Ok - thanks.  My first attempt to do that ended up with a bit of a mess - would not build and missing DLL's. Loads of errors.  If I create another project  then I can drag Folders froom an existing project onto the new project?

Comment: The namespace is unlikely to reflect the assembly if you just c&p the files (which is more a maintainability issue, than a imminent one).

Comment: Ok sure - I can change afterwards once its working.  Should a Project typically contain just the one namespace?  Is that a usual approach?   Haviong looked into this a littl further I was unaware of the 5MB memory limit in tehb ackground task and I suspect it may be difficult for me to open and access the database to update my live tile without breaking this limit.

Comment: It's normal that a namespace reflect the assembly name. Such as `<MyCompany>.Data` is both assembly-name and namespace. You would probably have something like: `<MyCompany>.Data`, `<MyCompany>.App`  , `<MyCompany>.Common` and `<MyCompany>.TaskAgent`.

Comment: And you have to test if the Sterling DB is fast enough to be used in a Live Tile. As long as you don't load the entire DB into memory, I wouldn't think of it being a problem.

Comment: I have one last query - by moving code out into a Class Library project - I can no longer access 'App'. It would mean I would have to have my own class  for settings and set these up (for the ones I want) when my Application starts up??

Comment: You shouldn't have to access anything from the App class from outside the Application assembly. Any *library* assembly (such as your Data assembly) shouldn't refer to the App class. If you need shared static settings, create a AppSettings class in a Common assembly.